# How do I make a min file in the same path or dest on gulp-rename and gulp-uglify?

Tags: javascript, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-uglify, gulp-rename

Hi everyone I hope you having a great day, I'm trying to find a way on how do I make a `min` file in the same path or `gulp.dest()` on ***gulp(gulp-uglify and gulp-rename)***. In my code below when I run my gulp it keeps on creating `*.min.js` , `*.min.min.js` , `*.min.min.min.js` so on and so forth unless I stop the terminal. How do I make my gulp create only one `*.min.js` at the same time it uglify's. I hope everyone can help me with this one. Thank You.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('./src/js/*.js')       
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename( {suffix: '.min'} ))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/js/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('browserSync', function(){

    browserSync.init({
        server : {
            baseDir : './'
        }
    });
    gulp.watch('./src/js/**.js', gulp.series('scripts'));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('scripts', 'browserSync'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because your `scripts` task is outputting the files to the same directory as you are watching:

```
.pipe(gulp.dest('./src/js/'))
```

and

```
gulp.watch('./src/js/**.js', gulp.series('scripts'));
```

So every time `scripts` runs and saves to that directory it triggers your `watch` again which fires `scripts`, etc., etc.

So either save your `.min`'s to a directory you are not watching or don't watch `.min` files.

BTW, change to `gulp.watch('./src/js/*.js', gulp.series('scripts'));`  // removed one asterisk

`gulp.watch(['./src/js/*.js', '!./src/js/*.min.js'], gulp.series('scripts'));`  //
might work - untested though.

Comment: Thank you Mark I just change my `.pipe(gulp.dest('./src/js/'))` to `.pipe(gulp.dest('./src/js/min/'))` to put my min files to a different path in the case on `gulp.watch(['./src/js/*.js', '!./src/js/*.min.js'], gulp.series('scripts'));` it still keeps on generate `*.min.js` so on and so forth , but I still looking forward putting my min file in the same folder.

Comment: Hi Mark I just play around the with my gulpjs.file since you mention this line `gulp.watch(['./src/js/*.js', '!./src/js/*.min.js'], gulp.series('scripts'))` I figured out I put it also to the `gulp.src` the entire line: `return gulp.src(['./src/js/*.js', '!./src/js/*.min.js']) ` and it works. Thank You

Comment: BTW Mark what is this `!` on the `!./src/js/*.min.js` how is it work?

Comment: The `!` is a negation indicator - so those files are not included in your watch list.  So any `.min.js` files are skipped.